# How do I download a sandbox project?

Tags: community-official-site

I want to develop the recommendation platform for job orders. In drupal there is the Prediction IO module but it is a sandbox project. How can I download it?

Comment: See also: [Is it possible to download sandbox projects with Drush?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/145489/how-do-i-download-a-sandbox-project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As reported in [Installing sandbox projects](https://www.drupal.org/node/1294804), sandbox projects don't have download links, since versions are not enabled for them. You need to use git to download the code.

Assuming you mean the [PredictionIO](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/mrded/2116851) module, that doesn't still have code, at the moment; it is reported in its [Version control](https://www.drupal.org/project/2116851/git-instructions) tab.

> No code is available for PredictionIO. File an issue or contact a maintainer if you have questions.

If there were code, you could download it with the following command.

```
git clone --branch master http://git.drupal.org/sandbox/mrded/2116851.git predictionio
```

In the *predictionio* directory, you would find the module code.

#### Update

On June 17, 2015, [the maintainer answered](https://www.drupal.org/node/2498765#comment-10031141) to [Code?](https://www.drupal.org/node/2498765) saying:

> Hi guys,
>
> We actually stopped developing of this module.
>   If you're interested, I can publish your codebase as full project and give you a maintainer permissions to fully control the module.

If nobody is going to offer to be maintainer of that sandbox project, the project will not have any code.

Comment: Ok. thank u.in that git clone link shows 404 Not Found error

Comment: It does because there have not been any commits. Once the project maintainer makes commits, the _Version control_ tab will reports how to clone the git repository.